# Conversion of code from Java to C# using Sharpen

Tags: java, c#, .net, eclipse, sharpen-tool

Do code conversion tools like Sharpen help in converting code from Java to C#? Does the converted code run on all Windows machines without trouble or changes have to be made? How efficient is this tool, does it completely remove the laborious line by line conversion method?

Comment: That will depend on the code being converted, but it's likely in most cases that manual changes would still be required. Recommendation: use such tools to port unit tests across, then use manual effort to make those tests pass.

Answer (score 1):

Sharpen generates a pretty good code, although there are some incompatibilities and weirdnesses due to the different semantics of Java and C#, I would say Sharpen converts about 95% or more of the code correctly.